# Summary Links Webpart - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I'm getting the following exception when I try to insert a Summary Links WebPart:

> Could not load XSL file. The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

I have checked my Site Features and Site Collection Features.

Both SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and SharePoint Server Publishing are active.

I'm not sure what else could be cause the issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: can you deactivate and reactivate both features and see if they are enabled without problems?

Comment: @TiagoDuarte Whenever I go to deactivate the features I get a warning saying "If you deactivate this feature, any user data or customizations associated with this feature might be lost. In addition, any active features and apps that depend on this feature might fail to function." I'm not sure if I would lose data

Comment: it seems that doing the mentioned steps helped others, but it is entirely up to you. there are other troubleshoot steps you can take, such as checking the ULS logs